# sh: SET: command not found in `npm start`

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-install, npm-scripts

I'm trying to run a react project . and after I run command : npm start , it gave me an error:

```
sh: SET: command not found
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! materials-trace@0.1.0 start: `SET PORT=3100 && node scripts/start.js`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the materials-trace@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/jzhu321/.npm/_logs/2019-04-22T09_29_51_770Z-debug.log
```

and I have found the config here in `package.json` :

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "SET PORT=3100 && node scripts/start.js",
    "build": "node scripts/build.js",
    "test": "node scripts/test.js"
  },
```

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: can you run the command - npm i

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Shell script doesnot have `SET` command, just had: `set`

it should be :

```
"start": "set PORT=3100 && node scripts/start.js",
```

Comment: For a cross-platform solution consider utilizing [cross-env](https://github.com/kentcdodds/cross-env) to set environment variables.

Comment: Correct: the "start" target in `package.json` was using Windows syntax instead of Linux shell syntax.  In this example, the "test" and "build" targets invoked NodeJS, which is platform agnostic - they were both OK.  One alternative for "start" is `set PORT=3100...`.  Another could be `export PORT=3100...`.  As RobC noted, yet another alternative is to use [cross-env](https://github.com/kentcdodds/cross-env).

Answer (score 6):

Change `SET` to `set`
your code should be

```
 "scripts": {
"start": "set PORT=3100 && node scripts/start.js",
"build": "node scripts/build.js",
"test": "node scripts/test.js"
},
```

Removing the `set` command will also result in error `sh: 1: PORT: not found` if there are spaces so you can use `PORT=3100`